# Postgresql 9.2.1 Normal user mode Vs Standalone Backend mode

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm having a remote machine that's using postgresql 9.2.1. Suddenly, i couldn't start my pgsql server(**pg_isready command is rejecting connections**). what my doubt is that, is there any possibility that i can start my database in **Standalone back end mode**, while it is not opening in **Normal user mode?**

And, what is the difference in starting the pgsql server in those two modes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using single user mode, look into the PostgreSQL server log file. That should tell you what the problem is.

In single-user mode, there will be just a single process accessing the database; none of the background processes are started. You'll be superuser, and the database process will last only for the duration of your session. This is something for emergency recovery, like when system tables are corrupted, you forgot your superuser password and so on.

In your case, single-user mode will probably only help if the database shut down because of an impending transaction ID wraparound. You can then issue the saving `VACUUM (FREEZE)` in single-user mode.

As soon as you have fixed your problem, upgrade to a supported release of PostgreSQL.

Comment: It is so helpful. Thank you.